# Validate all inputs located in different tabs

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, tabs, laravel-5.1

I have a form, I divide its inputs in two parts in two tabs like this :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
              <li class="tab active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#infos">General Infos</a></li>
              <li class="tab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#other">Others</a></li>

            </ul>    
                <div class="tab-content">
                   <div class="tab-pane active" id="infos">
                    {!! BootForm::open()->action( route('admin.user.create') )->put()->class('validModal')->id('createUserForm') !!}
                    {!! BootForm::text('Last Name', 'lastname')->placeholder('bkf') !!}
                    {!! BootForm::text('First Name', 'firstname')->placeholder('aek') !!}
                    {!! BootForm::text('Username', 'username')->placeholder('bkf.aek') !!}
                    {!! BootForm::email('Email', 'email')->placeholder('bkf@aek.com') !!}
                    ...
                  </div>
                 <div class="tab-pane" id="other">
                    {!! BootForm::select('Grade', 'grade_id')->options($grades)->select('') !!} 
                    {!! BootForm::password('Password', 'password') !!}
                    {!! BootForm::password('Password confirmation', 'password_confirmation') !!}                
                    ...                        
                  </div>

                </div>
```

When I submit the form with missed values I get errors only in the first tab, so how can I display them in the second tab when I click on tab ?
I'm looking for something like this :

```
$("li.tab").click(function (){                    

        errors =  response.errors;
        // Iterate through errors object.
        $.each(errors, function(field, message) {
            console.error(field+': '+message);

            var formGroup = $('[name='+field+']', form).closest('.form-group');
            formGroup.addClass('has-error').append('<p class="help-block">'+message+'</p>');
        });            

 });
```

Any idea please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol I got the solution by editing the code as this :

```
{!! BootForm::open()->action( route('admin.user.create') )->put()->class('validModal')->id('createUserForm') !!}    
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
              <li class="tab active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#infos">General Infos</a></li>
              <li class="tab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#other">Others</a></li>

            </ul>    
                <div class="tab-content">
                   <div class="tab-pane active" id="infos">
                  {!! BootForm::text('Last Name', 'lastname')->placeholder('bkf') !!}
                  ...
```